# Mounting a network folder on a local computer

Tags: networking, mount, disk

I'm trying to mount a folder from a different computer as a local mount on mine.

Both mine and the other computer (our home server) are Ubuntu, both running 14.04. The folder I want to mount locally is on Disk 3, called `theatre` (inside another folder also called `theatre`) and it's mounted in the `/mnt/` folder, so the path to it is `~/mnt/theatre/theatre/`, the network address of the server is 192.168.2.15.

I'm trying to mount the folder locally inside the `Videos` folder so that path is `/home/peter/Videos`.

So far I've tried:

```
$ sudo mount cifs//192.168.2.15/mnt/theatre/theatre /home/peter/Videos
mount: special device cifs//192.168.2.15/mnt/theatre/theatre does not exist
```

I've also tried:

```
$ sudo mount //192.168.2.15/mnt/theatre/theatre /home/peter/Videos
Password for root@//192.168.2.15/mnt/theatre/theatre: 
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
```

And:

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="c88ee187-d2b5-406f-90ed-e8ff3075ace1" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="b1bc3038-14d8-4752-b494-70a42e3e3b05" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="DISK 1" UUID="50EE-3B7A" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="DISK 2" UUID="7780-4603" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Disk 3" UUID="8d70789a-19a7-4aae-8f0c-2f93a7e172e2" TYPE="ext3"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Samba loaded on both systems?

Comment: Yes, Samba is installed on both systems. Question: do I need Samba if both systems are Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to connect to a Samba share (cifs)

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2208624) has been helpful to other users.

In answer to your comment, No. If your not sharing with Windows users you can simply use NFS which is typically faster.

Comment: That guide and the guide it referred to helped very much. I had an addition to the smb.conf file which was incorrect. Once corrected with the right path, it worked perfectly!